# How to programatically edit HTML files from an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin that needs to add new tags and attributes to existing tags to HTML files, the files might not be opened in the editor, but they will existing under a project in the workspace, does Eclipse provides a standard API to modify HTML files?

Comment: Core Eclipse doesn't haven't anything specific to HTML. The Web Tools plugins might have something.

Comment: If you don't find anything and need to manually manipulate HTML files take a look at http://jsoup.org/.

Comment: I'm mostly commenting to bump :)